# Unity sprite takes 5 times more memory in profiler

Tags: unity, sprites, memory, profiler

So as stated I have a sprite that when compressed takes 2 MB. But when I look into the memory in the profiler, it says that the sprite uses 10 MB! This happens both when I profile in the unity editor and on my android device. And this is not the only sprite that takes more memory than it should, but others take double the memory. Here is an image of how the import settings. All import settings are the same afaik. I have tried disabling the 3 ticked boxes and couldn't see any change in memory in the profiler. I would appreciate some help :)

[image]

Here is where I look to see the size of the compressed image:

[image]

Comment: For this specific example, 1024x2048 @ 8 bpp = 2 MiB and uncompressed 1024x2048 @ 32 bpp = 8 MiB, which together sum to the 10 MiB you're seeing. So, one possibility is that the game is storing both a ETC2 UNorm copy of the texture *and* an uncompressed RGBA32 version. This might be due to how the profiler works - keeping a PC-readable format to use on that side. When you say you see this same usage on-device, is that when you're running with it connected to your PC for profiling, or do you also observe this in a standalone build when not connected to the PC at all?

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, I am profiling the game with my android device connected to my PC. I am not sure how to profile otherwise. So are you saying that the actual memory usage might not be as big as the one shown by the profiler?

Comment: Profiling can add some overhead, so it's not impossible. At this stage though it's just a guess. [Searching for "unity memory usage runtime android"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+memory+usage+runtime+android&ia=web) [turns up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android/19267315#19267315) [some leads you could try](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-get-system-memory-size-of-android-devices-on-runtime.84620/) to test whether this guess could be on the right track.